# Print a map with markers and text details with Python

Tags: python, twitter, leaflet, tweepy, folium

I am currently working on a project, the idea is to extract tweets (with geo enabled) from a Hashtag and to print a map (with Folium). Inside the map, I should have markers according to the user locations and when I click at the marker I should have the text of the tweet. But currently I only have a map and the markers.

This is my code :

```python
import pandas as pd
import folium, ast

locations = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv', usecols=[3]).dropna()

l_locations = []

for loc in locations.values:
    l_locations.append(ast.literal_eval(loc[0])['coordinates'])

print_tweet_map = folium.Map(location=[48.864716, 2.349014], zoom_start=8, tiles='Mapbox Bright')

for geo in l_locations:
    folium.Marker(location=geo).add_to(print_tweet_map)

print_tweet_map.save('index.html')
```

Can you guys help me to print the markers and the text details of the tweet ?
Thanks in advance.

PS : I have currently :
[image: Europe map]

Comment: What have you tried in order to take user input and/or display tweet details?

Comment: Hello @Aaron3468 I know how I can print the text details by changing folium.Marker(location=geo).add_to(print_tweet_map) to folium.Marker(location=geo, popup=tweets).add_to(print_tweet_map). But I don't know how to retrieve tweets with my actual code

Comment: What data exists inside `tweets.csv`? It looks like the third value in each row corresponds to location, but perhaps it would be helpful if you posted a short excerpt of the file. Twitter's api seems to provide json and presumably the first field would be a user_id. You'll want to extract the field containing the tweet's permalink and the field containing its text. I believe the `popup` argument is all that folium requires to make text show on clicks. The `tooltip` argument allows a preview on hover.

Comment: Only 4 columns : created_at, user, text, geo (i posted some lines from it below)

Answer (score 0):

Some lines of the csv file :

```js
created_at,user,text,geo
2017-09-30 15:28:56,yanceustie,"RT @ChelseaFC: .@AlvaroMorata and @marcosalonso03 have been checking out the pitch ahead of kick-off..., null
2017-09-30 15:48:18,trendinaliaVN,#CHEMCI just started trending with 17632 tweets. More trends at ... #trndnl,"{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [21.0285, 105.8048]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine `read_csv` closely and then use it to retrieve the tweet text as well. Reading folium documentation, the `popup` seems the most relevant place to put each tweet's text.

Also you iterate over the same things 2 times. You can reduce those into 1 iteration loop that places a tweet on the map. (Imagine the map as your empty list you were appending to). No need to be overly sequential.

```
import pandas as pd
import folium, ast

frame = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv', usecols=[2, 3], names=['text', 'location'], header=None).dropna()

print_tweet_map = folium.Map(location=[48.864716, 2.349014], zoom_start=8, tiles='Mapbox Bright')

for index, item in frame.iterrows():
    loc = item.get('location')
    text = item.get('text')
    geo = ast.literal_eval(loc[0])['coordinates']

    folium.Marker(location=geo, popup=text) \ 
                .add_to(print_tweet_map)

print_tweet_map.save('index.html')
```

This should work, or very close to work, but I don't have a proper computer handy for testing.

Comment: I have this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "print_map.py", line 11, in <module>
    geo = ast.literal_eval(loc[0])['coordinates']
  File "C:\Users\Ajanthan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ast.py",
line 85, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Users\Ajanthan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ast.py",
line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x04F84CB0>

Comment: And also why did you use a \ in line 13 ?

Comment: @E Ajanthan Ah, seems like you will need to debug what `loc[0]` means. I probably messed up naming the columns when I used `read_csv`. The `\` just extends a line to the next line; it can make long lines a lot easier to read.

Comment: I have this error now : print_tweet_map = folium.Map(location=[48.864716, 2.349014], zoom_start=8, tiles='Mapbox Bright')

for index, item in frame.iterrows():
    loc = item.get('location')
    text = item.get('text')
    geo = ast.literal_eval(loc[0])['coordinates']

    folium.Marker(location=geo, popup=text) \ 
                .add_to(print_tweet_map)

print_tweet_map.save('index.html') Can you help me with this please :)